# Taking template class as a general argument, without specifying template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I've got a fairly unique situation.

I've got a structure resembling the following code, where a class template inherits from its own template argument, which may be a certain `BaseClass`, or any of its subclasses.

```
class BaseClass { 
... 
virtual void BaseMethod();
};

class DerivedClass { 
... 
virtual void BaseMethod(); // DerivedClass Overrides some of baseclass's methods

void DerivedMethod(); // And it has a few of its own
};

template <class T>
class ClassTemplate : public T {
...
// Some validation to ensure that this class template extends
// either BaseClass or one of its derived classes
void ValidateTemplate(const BaseClass& c) {}
...
}
```

The point where this becomes tricky is when I want to take a template class argument that is templated after the baseclass, or one of its subclasses:

```
void func(ClassTemplate& c) { ... c.BaseMethod(); }
```

Of course, this doesn't compile as its missing its template arguments. However, I'm looking for a solution that will function like the following, without having to actually specify the following function overloads:

```
void func(ClassTemplate<BaseClass>& c) { ... c.BaseMethod(); }
void func(ClassTemplate<DerivedClass>& c) { ... c.BaseMethod(); }
```

On top of that, one of my other classes contains a list of ClassTemplate pointers:

```
class ClassWithList {
std::list<ClassTemplate<BaseClass>*> l;
...
}
```

With the above, I want the list l to contain both `ClassTemplate<BaseClass>` objects, and `ClassTemplatE<DerivedClass>` objects. This has the same root problem - hoping that the latter could be interpreted as the former, as is the case for most implicit conversions in C++. Is this particular kind of conversion possible to do with templates? Or is there an alternate workaround?

**Notes:**

In `func`, none of`DerivedClass`'s functions are used - just like if I had taken a `BaseClass` argument, I want to be able to access its public members.

However, it is important that I don't take `BaseClass` as an argument. This is because I need to access members of the `ClassTemplate` object, which are unique to `ClassTemplate` itself.

Additionally, I can't resort to using multiple inheritance (Have `DerivedClass` subclass both `ClassTemplate` and `BaseClass`) as this will result in diamond inheritance, thus creating an inheritance hierarchy too complicated for simple virtual inheritance.

Comment: Are you ok with template function `template <typename T> void func(ClassTemplate<T>& c);` ?

Comment: BTW, in C++11, you may use `static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value, "Type should derived from BaseClass");` instead of `ValidateTemplate`.

Comment: Good point Jarod, I've never tried that. That would help in a number of places. As for your first question, see my response below. I've update the original post to reflect it.

Comment: What does `ClassTemplate` do?  Is every instance of `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` in a `ClassTemplate<>`?  Have you considered CRTP?

Comment: The common base class between `ClassTemplate<BaseClass>` and `ClassTemplate<DerivedClass>` is `BaseClass` and not `ClassTemplate<BaseClass>`, so you can't stock them inside `std::list<ClassTemplate<BaseClass>*>` (but you can in `std::list<BaseClass*>`)

Comment: ClassTemplate was created so that the exact implementation of BaseClass could be specified as a template argument. In my program, ClassTemplate is subclassed into different objects that share ClassTemplate and BaseClass functionality. As for CRTP, I'll have to look into it - that might be what I'm going for, but I've never looked into it until now.

Comment: @Jarod, that's correct, however that would disallow the access to any ClassTemplate member functions. Right now, I'm considering doing that, and static casting the BaseClass objects into ClassTemplate objects. Not sure - feels messy.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, it sounds like you want a function template:

```
template <typename T>
void func(ClassTemplate<T>& c) { ... c.BaseMethod(); }
```

For handling the list case, one option is to have a third class that you use as the interface:

```
struct ClassTemplateBase {
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class ClassTemplate : public T, public ClassTemplateBase {
  // ...
}
```

then you can have a `std::list<ClassTemplateBase *>`.  This avoids the diamond inheritance issue.

Comment: +1 this would certainly seem the most logical choice given what the OP has described.

Comment: You would think so, however it's far from elegant. There are many functions that use ClassTemplate<BaseClass>, as both return values and pointer members, as well as arguments. For example, one of my classes has a List of ClassTemplate<BaseClass>* - template functions would only solve a few of the problems, however converting the aforementioned classes into templates themselves is entirely inappropriate.

Comment: @Tedium It's hard to see what is your concern with this answer. Can you elaborate? For example,  "I want to write this (example) but it fails to compile", like you did in the main question.

Comment: I've already updated the original post to reflect this - right below the function examples.